# Array name not passed in trancluded directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use transclude directive. when i try to pass `array`  name in sticky variable then it is not passed but string value in `name` variable is working .I have defined array and name string in controller .

**Note :: menu which is written out of my-box directive is taking arry name and working fine.**

Please suggest,

**HTML ::**

```
<my-box
    bgcolor="#EFF"
    my-title="buzz2222"
    my-height="170"
    my-width="1050"
    my-color="#1a1a1a"
    my-bgcolor="#FBFBF9"
    my-collapseoption=true
    my-widgetno="1"
    my-template="latest_template.html"
    my-url="Business.json"
    sticky="top_sticky"
    my-toolbar=false
    save="saveChanges('custom boxective')">
      <menu sticky="items2" name="name" ></menu>
    </my-box>

    <menu sticky="items2" name="name" ></menu>
```

**Angular Directive ::**

```
 // add a directive
app.directive("myBox", function($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {
            items : '=',
            myTitle : '@', // by value
            myHeight : '@', // by value
            myWidth : '@', // by value
            myColor : '@', // by value
            myBgcolor : '@', // by value
            myWidgetno : '@', // by reference
            myTemplate : '@',
            /* merge */
            sticky: '=sticky',
            myToolbar : '@', /* merge */
            myUrl : '@',
            myCollapseoption : '@', // by reference
            save : '&', // event

        },
        transclude:true,
        templateUrl : function(el, attrs) {
            return 'generic_widget.html';
        },
        controller : function($http, $scope, $element, $sce, $templateCache, $compile, $attrs) {


        },
        replace : false,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.css("background", attrs.myBgcolor);
            element.css("color", attrs.myColor);
            element.css("width", attrs.myWidth + 'px');
            element.css("height", attrs.myHeight + 'px');
            element.find('#jhelp').html('Now trying get jquery help');
        }
    };
});
app.directive('menu', function() {
    return {
        //require: '^myBox',
        scope:{
            name:'@',
             sticky:'='},
        restrict: 'E',      
        template: '<h3>{{name}}I am coming from Hello {{sticky}} </h3><div ng-repeat="t in sticky">anam repeat </div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs ,mybox) {
            //console.log('menu scope  is '+mybox.sticky);

        },
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to $compile document [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile)

scope:{} will create an isolated scope which like `$scope = {}`
Any variable which defined in controller's scope will inaccessible in this directive and descendent scope.
if you want to use an variable reference inside a directive with isolated scope. you can define a scope property of bi-directional binding ( = ) with the same name.
In your case, you can define an `items2` scope property in `my-box` directive

```
 // add a directive
app.directive("myBox", function($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict : "E",
        scope : {
            items2: '=', // this will be used in menu directive
            // ...
            // others not change.
});
```

Further more. If you want to access controller's scope without define every property with the variable name. You can use `scope: true` instead of `scope:{}`
In this case. use $parse service to access the variable reference.

Comment: i cant use scope true as i want to use it with different array , also $ parent i cant use as i need array name

Comment: is there any why to pass array name with <menu > directive >?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to access controller's scope inside an isolated scope. Although you can pass the $scope itself to your directive. but it is not a good practice.